# Returning documents using multi-valued field

Tags: solr

I'm quite new to Solr and I'm supporting an existing Solr search engine which was written by someone else. I've been reading on Solr for the last couple of weeks so I'd consider myself beyond the basics.

A particular field, let's say name, is multi-valued. For example, a document has a field "name" with values "Alice, Trudy". We want that the document is returned when "Alice" or "Trudy" is input and not when "Alice Trudy" is entered. Currently the document is even with "Alice Trudy". How could this be done?

Thanks a lot!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

If the field value is "Alice, Trudy", normally solr/lucene should match for "alice" or "trudy". If not, there could be special "Text Analysis" or stemming options active for this field.

Take a look at the part "text analysis" at the solr documentation: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Text+Analysis
and: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters